# What "natural" functions besides $g(x) = x$ and $g(x) =\dfrac{c^{x}}{c^{x}+c^{1/2}} $ satisfy $g(x)+g(1-x) = 1$?

Tags: summation, functional-equations

I'm not quite sure
how I should state this question.

This is one way:

What "natural" functions besides
$g(x) = x$
and
$g(x)
=\dfrac{c^{x}}{c^{x}+c^{1/2}}
$
satisfy
$g(x)+g(1-x) = 1$?

By "natural" I mean that
$g(x)$
is defined by a single expression
for $0 \le x \le 1$,
and not separately for
$0 \le x \le \frac12$
and
$\frac12 \le x \le 1$.

That is because,
as I will show,
if
$g(x)+g(1-x) = 1$
then
$\int_0^1 g(x) dx
=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} g\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
=\frac12
$
for all $n$.

Another possible way
is to ask if
$g(x)
=\dfrac{c^{x}}{c^{x}+c^{1/2}}
$
then show that
$\sum_{k=0}^n g(k/n)
=\frac{n+1}{2}
$.

This is inspired 
by my solution to
[Show that this sum is an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474849/show-that-this-sum-is-an-integer)

First,
I will show that
if
$g(x)+g(1-x)
= 1
$,
then
$\int_0^1 g(x) dx
=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} g\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
=\frac12
$
for all $n$.

If
$G(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} g(k/n)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
2G(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} g(k/n)+\sum_{k=0}^{n} g(k/n)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n1} g(k/n)+\sum_{k=0}^{n} g((n-k)/n)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (g(k/n)+ g((n-k)/n))\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 1\\
&=n+1\\
\text{so}\\
G(n)
&= \frac{n+1}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

If
$I
=\int_0^1 g(x) dx
$,

$\begin{array}\\
2I
&=\int_0^1 g(x) dx+\int_0^1 g(x) dx\\
&=\int_0^1 g(x) dx+\int_0^1 g(1-x) dx\\
&=\int_0^1 (g(x)+g(1-x)) dx\\
&=\int_0^1 1 dx\\
&= 1\\
\text{so}\\
I
&= \frac12\\
&= \frac{G(n)}{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Now,
I will show that
if
$g(x)
=\dfrac{c^{x}}{c^{x}+c^{1/2}}
$
then
$g(x)+g(1-x)
=1
$.

$\begin{array}\\
g(x)+g(1-x)
&=\dfrac{c^{x}}{c^{x}+c^{1/2}}+\dfrac{c^{1-x}}{c^{1-x}+c^{1/2}}\\
&=\dfrac{c^{x}(c^{1-x}+c^{1/2})+c^{1-x}(c^{x}+c^{1/2})}{(c^{x}+c^{1/2})(c^{1-x}+c^{1/2})}\\
&=\dfrac{(c+c^{x}c^{1/2})+(c+c^{1-x}c^{1/2})}{c+c^{1/2}(c^{x}+c^{1-x})+c}\\
&=\dfrac{2c+c^{1/2}(c^{x}+c^{1-x})}{2c+c^{1/2}(c^{x}+c^{1-x})}\\
&= 1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: $g: x \mapsto 1/2$?

Comment: See Greg Martin's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is *any* odd function whatsoever, then $g(x) = f(x-\frac12)+\frac12$ satisfies $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$. So for example, $g(x) = (x-\frac12)^3+\frac12=x^3-\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{3 x}{4}+\frac{3}{8}$ and $g(x)=\arctan(x-\frac12)+\frac12$ and $g(x) = e^{x-1/2}-e^{1/2-x}+\frac12$ are all examples. Your second example is of this form as well, with $f(x) = \frac12(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})/(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2})$.

Comment: Nice. 9 more to go...