# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^n \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(n-x)}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I found this problem on an old FB post and have just been humbled by it.

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[0,n]$ such that $n > 0$ and $f(x) + f(n - x)$ does not vanish on $[0,n]$ then evaluate

$$
\int_0^n \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(n-x)}dx
$$

Any clues/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Change of variables $u=n-x$, then add two integrals.

Comment: Very similar to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475890/what-natural-functions-besides-gx-x-and-gx-dfraccxcxc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle I = \int_0^n \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(n-x)}dx$

Let $y = n-x$ Then $dy = -dx$ and
$\displaystyle I = -\int_n^0 \frac{f(n-y)}{f(n-y) + f(y)}dy
= \int_0^n \frac{f(n-x)}{f(n-x) + f(x)}dx$

So
\begin{align}
  2I &= I + I\\
  2I &= \int_0^n \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(n-x)}dx 
       + \int_0^n \frac{f(n-x)}{f(n-x) + f(x)}dx\\
  2I &= \int_0^n \frac{f(x)+f(n-x)}{f(x) + f(n-x)}dx\\
  2I &= \int_0^n dx\\
  2I &= n\\
  I &= \frac n2
\end{align}

Comment: As a side note a nice particular example is when $f(x)=\sin x$ and $n=\pi / 2$

Answer (score 3):

Let $I$ be our integral.  Make the substitution  $u=n-x$.

After you have completed the change of variable, change the dummy variable of integration back to $x$. We now  have a new expression for $I$. Add the old expression, and *look*.